# App gives Bad Access Error in adding Fading Gradients to UIScrollView

Tags: iphone, ios, uiscrollview

I am trying to add fading gradients at both end of scrollView Which work Great in simulator but when i run it on Device than it was giving me bad access error.

Here is my code to add fading gradients in scrollView which i have get from [this](http://www.cocoanetics.com/2011/08/adding-fading-gradients-to-uitableview/) link. In .m file at line 13 it gives error

**.h File**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController
{
    CAGradientLayer *maskLayer;
}
```

**.m File**

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    if (!maskLayer)
    {
        maskLayer = [CAGradientLayer layer];

        CGColorRef outerColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:1.0 alpha:0.5].CGColor;
        CGColorRef innerColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:1.0 alpha:0.0].CGColor;

       //here it gives bad access error
        maskLayer.colors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:(__bridge id)(outerColor),(__bridge id)(innerColor),(__bridge id)(innerColor), (__bridge id)(outerColor), nil];


        maskLayer.locations = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.0],[NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.05],[NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.95],[NSNumber numberWithFloat:1.0], nil];

        maskLayer.bounds = CGRectMake(0, 0,scrollView.frame.size.width,scrollView.frame.size.height);

           maskLayer.frame = CGRectMake(0, scrollView.frame.origin.y,scrollView.frame.size.width,scrollView.frame.size.height);

        [self.view.layer addSublayer:maskLayer];
    }
}

- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)ascrollView
{
    [CATransaction begin];
    [CATransaction setDisableActions:YES];
    maskLayer.position = CGPointMake(0, ascrollView.contentOffset.y);
    [CATransaction commit];
}
```

Comment: .h file `]` is that a typo?

Comment: Try storing the UIColors in their own variables (just a hunch that the CGColorRef might be becoming invalid before you use it).

Comment: I have tried to use it but same problem is occuring

Comment: Try it in `viewDidAppear`

Comment: @LithuT.V same problem occurs if do that

Comment: Try  `CGColorRef outerColor = [UIColor greenColor].CGColor;`

Comment: whats the os of device?